# Using Awk to add hostname to line

Tags: bash, awk, host

I have this text file TopIP.txt:
(fiction IPs and hostname)

```
Top destination for Source IP 1.2.3.4
    34322 2.3.4.5
    455   2.3.4.6
```

I want to add the hostname to each IP at the end of the line. My desire output is this:

```
Top destination for Source IP 1.2.3.4 hostname3.com
    34322 2.3.4.5 hostname1.com
    455   2.3.4.6 hostname2.com
```

I made it happen last week and didnt save and now i cant replicate it.

my code started something similar to this:

```
cat TopIP.txt | awk '{print $0, system("host " $NF)}'
```

Comment: What problem are you having with your approach?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: cant figure out how to isolate the hostname from the host command and addindg it to the end of the line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd stick with bash:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    set -- $line
    echo "$line $(host ${!#})"
done < TopIP.txt > newfile
```

Comment: and what would i do if I only want the last string/part of the command host

Comment: You'd pipe the output of the host command into a command that would output only the part you want. Perhaps `host ${!#} | sed 's/^.* //'`

Comment: why use `set -- $line` and not use `$(host $line)` ?

Comment: Because we only want to send the last word in the line to the `host` command, not the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with sed easily:

```
sed -i "0,/IP/s/$/ `hostname -f`/" filename
```

That will simply add the current fully qualified hostname (hostname.domain.tld) to the end of the line containing IP. Before you use either, you need to check your networking config to insure either `hostname -f` or `host ${!#}` return the proper hostname. It is not uncommon for network configuration issues to cause invalid hostname returns.